# Tic-Tac-Toe card games?

Tags: playing-cards, game-development, tic-tac-toe

My family is developing a game based off of Tic-Tac-Toe. Only the objective is the same though. Are there any other games out there with similar goals and objectives based off of Tic-Tac-Toe?

Comment: How similar are you looking for?  There are *many* games where the goal is to form a line of your own pieces -- too many to make this a good question unless you're looking for something more specific.

Comment: 3 in a row as objective-with cards Specifically listed as a game based off of tic-tac-toe

Comment: So you're looking for games that a) use cards and b) have a goal of getting three of your symbol in a row?  I think that's specific enough.

Comment: yes that is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

There are, in fact, already card games where you try to get three of your symbol in a row.

[Tic Tac Toe: jeu de réflexion](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/155256/tic-tac-toe-jeu-de-reflexion), for example.